# duplicate implementation of controller file?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, uiviewcontroller

I get this message in my debugger every time I run my app, I want to get rid of it:

`objc[1326]: Class RSKImageCropViewController is implemented in both /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5C326583-4353-4341-B5BF-A8CA0713B772/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RSKImageCropper.framework/RSKImageCropper and /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5C326583-4353-4341-B5BF-A8CA0713B772/MyApp.app/MyApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined`

What is this implying? and I do not know where to search to find these files so I can possibly remove one.. Where should I locate them?

the only two visual places I have the files implemented in my project are here in my regular project target navigator:

[image]

and down below in my pods target navigator section:

[image]

so is this causing that error? please take in consideration the directory locations the error is referring to

Comment: Do you implement `RSKImageCropViewController` in your program?

Comment: yes, but i don't see where i would implement it twice  @anhtu

Comment: `RSKImageCropper.framework` already has one `RSKImageCropViewController`. So you can't implement `RSKImageCropViewController` again. Try with another name.

Comment: so should i delete one or?

Comment: Yes, delete one, or rename name of class

Comment: i changed the class of the implementation file but still same message

Comment: let me provide screenshot of my project navigator

Comment: please check updated question @anhtu

Comment: You should use `refactor` to change name of a class

Comment: what is that? @anhtu and check question, are these the locations that the error is pointing too?

Comment: You implement 2 `RSKImageCropViewController `, so sure it causes error. Refactor name of class, name of 1  `RSKImageCropViewController`.

Comment: how do i refactor the name of the class? @anhtu

Comment: Right click on name of class -> refactor

Comment: never mind i got it, yes i fixed it. thank you

Comment: How do you fix it. Can you explain?

Comment: i just deleted the `RSKImageCropController` i had in my project navigator, and kept the one I already have in my framework

Comment: 2 `RSKImageCropController` are the same? For sure you have to delete one. I said it before. Anyway happy when the problem is solved. Please write an answer.